# JavaScript Play/Pause Audio Toggle

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8LczkwLz/19/

HTML:

```
<audio class="flashcardAudio" preload='none'>
    <source src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1538714/article_resources/song.m4a" type='audio/mpeg' />
</audio>

<a class="speakerClicked">
    <img src="http://codropspz.tympanus.netdna-cdn.com/codrops/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/play1-150x150.png"/>
</a>
```

JS:

```
var flashcardAudio = document.getElementsByClassName('flashcardAudio'),
control = document.getElementsByClassName('speakerClicked');

control.onclick = function () {
  pause_html='<img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/media-and-navigation-buttons- square/512/Button_4-128.png">';
  speaker_html='<img src="http://codropspz.tympanus.netdna-cdn.com/codrops/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/play1-150x150.png">';

    // Update the Button
    var pause = control.innerHTML === pause_html;
    control.innerHTML = pause ? speaker_html : pause_html;

    // Update the Audio
    var method = pause ? 'pause' : 'play';
    flashcardAudio[method]();

    // Prevent Default Action
    return false;
};
```

On click of play button I would like to see it toggle to pause button and vice a versa. Seems to be issues entering function in JS though since the alert message never triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to target the specific elements, just replace `line 1 and 2` of your JS by :

```
var flashcardAudio = document.getElementsByClassName('flashcardAudio')[0],
control = document.getElementsByClassName('speakerClicked')[0];
```

And remove the space in the pause button img url.

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8LczkwLz/28/)

Comment: Thanks, this one was driving me crazy! I'll accept answer when SO allows.

Comment: You're welcome ;) There was also a space in the 'pause' button URL I removed it and it works well (updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8LczkwLz/23/))

Comment: Thanks again :) I'll have to review targeting